# Filter tablix with two "Like" operations combined by an "Or"

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I need to filter on a tablix to return where values in the string contains "*BLACK*" OR "*RED*":

```
Expression:  =Fields!DrawOfficeNum.Value Like "*BLACK*" AND Fields!DrawOfficeNum.Value Like "*RED*"
Operator:    Like
Value:       True
```

I'm getting no results back and I know there is results.  Help will be greatly apreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do it like this:

**Expression (Text type):**

```
=IIf(InStr(Fields!DrawOfficeNum.Value, "BLACK") > 0 or InStr(Fields!DrawOfficeNum.Value, "RED") > 0
    , "Include"
    , "Exclude")
```

**Operator:** =

**Value:** Exclude

[image]

This gives results:

[image]

Only thing to not is that I turned the filter from a **Boolean** to a **Text** type - in the past I've always had problems with **Boolean** filters and the option above works well, as per the screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

Quote, emphasis mine:

> I need to filter...where values in the string contains "BLACK" **OR** "RED":

Quote, emphasis mine:

> =Fields!DrawOfficeNum.Value Like "*BLACK*" **AND** Fields!DrawOfficeNum.Value Like "*RED*"

Change the `AND` into `OR` in your expression, then you're good to go.

Comment: Hah, forest/trees, etc. If this is all it takes then definitely the easiest solution!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work more easily in this way :

- In the "Expression" box, put [DrawOfficeNum]
- In the Operator box, choose In
- In the Value box, put BLACK; RED

It will know that you works on a string type (depends on your field type), and generate a list separated with ;

If i am wrong, can anyone tell me?